# Scrapy crawler unstable, sometimes works sometimes won't

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy, web-crawler, pipeline

My crawler would work sometimes -crawls and scrapes but sometimes just crawls and wouldnt scrape anything without me changing anything on the code :/ I don't understand. There is no error code or anything. It looks like this when it wont scraepe;

```
2017-02-05 23:52:00 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/s/srs=9187220011&rh=n%3A283155> (referer: None)
2017-02-05 23:52:00 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-02-05 23:52:00 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 712,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 3964,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 6, 5, 52, 0, 552000),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 7,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'log_count/WARNING': 1,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 6, 5, 51, 59, 328000)}
```

I'm trying to scrape this website and put it in mongodb using mongodb pipeline. Like it actually works, but sometime it won't work, it's pretty weird. 
I'm thinking that this could be pipeline problem, but not sure.. Any suggestions? How can I check what's wrong. I'm connected to mongodb, like as I'm doing this mongod is running

This is my mongodbpipeline;

```
class MongoDBPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        connection = pymongo.MongoClient(
            settings['MONGODB_SERVER'],
            settings['MONGODB_PORT']
        )
        db = connection[settings['MONGODB_DB']]
        self.collection = db[settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION']]

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        valid = True
        for data in item:
            if not data:
                valid = False
                raise DropItem("Missing {0}!".format(data))
        if valid:
            self.collection.insert(dict(item))
            log.msg("link added to MongoDB database!",
                    level=log.DEBUG, spider=spider)
        return item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sir you are scraping Amazon, a very famous and anti-crawler website.

Its because sometimes they send you response but sometimes they just show captcha due to continuous requests and not the actual webpage.

You will have to use proxies in order to scrape Amazon smoothly, and even with proxies you will see many captchas, but you have to retry those URLs for which you got captcha.

you can use this piece of code to see if there is captcha in page.

```
if response.css('#captchacharacters').extract_first():
      print("Captcha found ")
```

Comment: I'm already using proxies, I have 5 individual proxies and I was randomly picking one for each request. How can I keep track of URL's that got captcha? like is there anyway to see that in the log. Thank you

Comment: RETRY_TIMES = 5
# Retry on most error codes since proxies fail for different reasons
RETRY_HTTP_CODES = [500, 503, 504, 400, 403, 404, 408]

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': 90,
    'scrapy_proxies.RandomProxy': 100,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
}

PROXY_LIST = 'list.txt'

Comment: is it one of the http codes above? If i get one of those I do retry but i guess captcha is different

Comment: also 5 proxies are not enough to scrape Amazon ... I scraped amazon and I had to use stormproxies, they provide proxies pool of 75000 ips. and still i used to see captcha when I scraped amazon

Comment: yeah, you were right, I was getting captcha's.  Would adding a download delay help the problem? What can I do about this?

Comment: You MUST have to use Lots Lots Lots proxies ... ... Believe me I did a big project to scrape Amazon, I had to scrape 1 millions URLs daily. I had to use stormproxies because they provide about 72k rotating proxies ... 

PS:

It also depends upon your needs as well. If your load is to crawl fw 100s Amazon URLs daily then 10-15 proxies with random delay between proxies is good for you.

Comment: Yeah I'm not doing anything that big, I need to crawl around 75k amazon urls but not daily maybe weekly. I just can't figure what's a good limit for concurrent request and what's good amount of delay to not to get capthca and get the work done.

Comment: with 72k rotating proxies, what were the limits you have used for concurrent_per_domain, concurrent_per_ip, download_delay, did you use autothrottle

Comment: To crawl 72k weekly, divide this 72k/7 and then crawl those URLs daily. And FYI you cannot 100% get away with captcha, with lots of proxies you still encounter captchas, but as soon you encounter, just re-scrape that URL with new IP/Proxy, to do this, create download middleware and inside process_response use the piece of code I pasted in my answer, if captcha comes, just re-send that request with dont_filter=True parameter.